# Intellij Kotlin - Missing proceed on errors

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

While coding Java one can set the configuration "Proceed on errors" for example on the eclipse compiler in Intellij.

Is there an equivalent for Kotlin?

My specific case right now: all code (written in Java) is build OK, junit tests (written in Kotlin) are broken. I'm trying to fix and build the tests one by one.

Kind regards,

GJS

Comment: So, there are several syntax problems in kotlin test files, but kotlin compiler shows you only one? Actually, I can't reproduce it - when I intentionally add some syntax errors, compiler shows them all without any additional configuration. What makes you think you got more than that one syntactic problem? What build tool do you use?

Comment: JFYI: In the new Kotlin/JS compiler there is such an experimental feature that allows you to compile code with errors, even syntactical

Comment: For Kotlin JVM compiler there is no such feature yet. Please watch the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-3321 for updates on this.